# Not able to understand some operations in rtlsdr library in python

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, frequency, software, software-development

Here is the part of the program I am having problems with:

```
 samples = sdr.read_samples(16*1024)
    power, _ = mlab.psd(samples, NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate /1e6)
```

NFFT is the data points iin each block of FFT and Fs is the sampling frequency. Now, here are my questions:

1. What does 12*1024 signify
2. why do we do sdr.sample_rate /1e6

Comment: Do have a look at the [matplotlib PSD docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html)... which say "The power spectral density Pxx ... The vector x is divided into NFFT length segments. Each segment is detrended ... and windowed ...  **The |fft(i)|2 of each segment i are averaged to compute Pxx**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one block can be read into the psd if you want a result that is averaged (thus usually smoother) over several blocks.

A sample rate in Hz can be divided by 1e6 if you want a spectral plot labeled in MHz, instead Hz.

Comment: ok , but what do you mean exactly by writing it as 16*1024, why not write it as 16384

Comment: You can write 16384 if you (and everybody reading it) knows how to divide by 1024 in their head quickly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The number of samples to read.
2. Probably because whoever wrote it wants the graph to read in MHz rather than Hz.

Comment: I get that it means the number of samples to read, but why write it as 16*1024 rather than 16384 samples

Comment: @RasenRhino readability.